# 1und1 url modification not allowed

Tags: .htaccess, web-hosting

I am trying to set up a website in 1und1.de. I have uploaded all the files, created all the database. But the problem comes when I click on the links on menu. It opens a blank page. It is working fine in my localhost as well as in my other hosting service. I need to make it work in 1und1.de. Their support is not so good. I have been stuck here for 2 weeks hoping to get a solution. All they tell me is to go to properties and change the permission settings. I have done that. Gives me an error everytime.

Is this because of the their .htaccess file? And I cannot override their file which is inside a /logs/ folder which is itself protected.

This is their .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
RemoveHandler .html
RemoveType .html
AddType text/html .html
Satisfy any
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from /* ip address here */
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /logs"
AuthUserFile /kunden/homepages/37/userId/htpasswd
Require user userId
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)$ ./site_contents.php?content=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index$ ./index.php [L]
```

If you have worked with 1und1.de then you may have encountered the same problem.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't had problems with 1&1 regarding URL rewrites. try your .htaccess without `./`, just `RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [L]`

Comment: If your .htaccess is in a subdirectory and not the document root you may have to add a `RewriteBase /directory`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I tried your solution but it is not working. How can the same .htaccess work in one hosting and not in the other one? When I upload the same files in my other server, it works fine.

Comment: http://testprep800.com/pages/contact

My server: http://alokpant.com/demo/testprep800/pages/contact

The same set of files...

Answer (score 0):

RemoveType directives are processed after any AddType directives no matter in what order you write them in the .htaccess-file. So in your case you have to remove the 'RemoveType .html'-line.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#removetype